# generation of unique keys

Tags: c

Given a number, how can I create a unique key from that number. This key should never be repeated when given different number. and when the same number is provided it should give back the same key that it generated earlier, i need this in my application. pls can you suggest any algorithm

Edited : sorry guys i changed the Q when you guys were answering the Q i thought the above Q be a better way of asking, my Q is in my B-tree i am storing the ipaddress (src ip and dst ip) of ipv4 i am generating the key for that using the destination ip, for eg: if i have a address 172.28.6.100 i generate a key using the last two bytes as 600 (6*100) now i have to store even the ipv6 address how can i generate a key for that i need to generate a uniqe key for each address.

Comment: We know you need it, or else you wouldn't be asking.

Comment: What kind of key do you need? If it were to be a number, you could just return the same number as well!

Comment: Have you entirely changed the question while people were writing answers???

Comment: Your question is not well-founded.  If the number of possible keys is smaller than the number of possible inputs, then multiple inputs _must_ map to the same key (Pigeonhole Principle).  If the number of possible keys is greater than or equal to the number of possible inputs, why are you looking for a hash?  You can just use the input itself as the key.  In short, you need to understand your problem before you can ask a question about it, never mind find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm (from the original question, where you stated you were generating a key `c*d` from the IP address `a.b.c.d`) doesn't even guarantee uniqueness for your *IPv4* addresses. `172.28.6.12` will have an identical key to `172.28.12.6` and `9.45.3.24` and `10.1.72.1` (among others).

That is an inevitable outcome of hashing where you map many items to one key.

My question is: *why* are you hashing. You can fit an IPv4 address into four bytes and an Ipv6 one into sixteen bytes. They're not so large that you couldn't use the entire address as the key, surely?

And, even if they *are* too large, if your requirement is to be unique across the entire allowable range of IP addresses, you may have to do that anyway. The only way to *guarantee* uniqueness is to limit the input values somehow.

---

Since you've changed your question to remove the specifics, I'll add this addendum. The reasoning behind my answer doesn't change.

If you're hashing data to generate keys, there are only two ways to guarantee uniqueness of the keys:

- use the same number of bits for the key as you do for the data; or
- limit the data somehow.

The first of those buys you very little. It's sometimes useful to map sparse data to contiguous indexes for efficient lookups but will not save you any space.

The second is often used where you know the data will be limited such as (1) all your IP addresses start with `10.1` or they're all integers between 1000 and 1099.

But, unless you choose one of those limitations, there's no way to guarantee there won't be a key collision.

Comment: @littleadv: in the original question.

Answer (score 3):

```
unsigned generate_key(int x) { return x; }
```

Always returns a different hash for a different input.  This is an *ideal perfect hash function*.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the IP address space you're dealing with is well constrained (i.e. you get to pick the numbers and they are part of a private network, e.g. 10.x.x.x), using the last two octets and multiplying them together will have collisions for different IP's whenever the final answer shares more than one multipler that can create the same key, the only way they would not collide is if all of the octets you used were prime numbers (which they cannot be).

Instead of creating a b-tree with key->value pairs, I would suggest that you use the IP address themselves for the key, though, I'm not sure what you would gain from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use hash algorithm? Given the number is a 4-bytes integer, any decent hash algorithm will give you what you need, just convert to ASCII as a string.

You can find a list of standard hash algorithms [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions).

**after your edit**

For using keys in your BTree (originally I read that as license keys, that's why I mentioned translating to ASCII) - there's no reason whatsoever not to use the destination IP in its entirety as a key (Be it IPv4 or IPv6, the most is 128 bits, very reasonable). Otherwise you cannot ensure uniqueness that you require unless you have some assumptions or knowledge on the network topography.